# Copy role assignments from one folder to another using CSOM C#

Tags: csom, role-assignment

I want to copy role assignments from one folder and  set it  to other folder

I am basically creating a subfolder and I want that folder to have same permission as its sibling

I tried

```
Folder sourceFolder = oWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Affaires/Test Affaire/Mails");
ctx.Load(sourceFolder);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Folder destinationFolder = folder.Folders.Add("Demo");  
destinationFolder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);
RoleAssignmentCollection roleAssignments = sourceFolder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments;
ctx.Load(roleAssignments);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (RoleAssignment item in roleAssignments)
        {
        //not sure what to do here!
         destinationFolder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add(item.PrincipalId, item.RoleDefinitionBindings);
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out

The below code worked for me

```
Folder sourceFolder = oWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Affaires/Test Affaire/Mails");
ctx.Load(sourceFolder);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Folder destinationFolder = folder.Folders.Add("Demo");
destinationFolder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);
RoleAssignmentCollection roleAssignments = sourceFolder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments;
ctx.Load(roleAssignments);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (RoleAssignment item in roleAssignments)
{
  ctx.Load(item);
  ctx.ExecuteQuery();
  destinationFolder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add(item.Member,item.RoleDefinitionBindings);
}
ctx.Load(destinationFolder);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```